# Sympy: how to calculate a derivative over squared symbol

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, sympy

I would like to calculate a derivative over a variation in normal distribution. All for getting known the estimator of variation using a Maximum Likelihood method.
That's my code.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

from sympy.solvers import solve

from sympy import Product, Function, oo, IndexedBase, diff, Eq, symbols, Sum, factorial, E, sqrt, pi, exp


x = IndexedBase('x')
i = symbols('i', positive=True)
n = symbols('n', positive=True)
s = symbols('s') # s = standard deviation
m = symbols('m') # m = expected value

def var(): # var = variance (function var() has been created as variance depends on standard deviation)
    return s*s

formula = (1/(s*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp((-1/2)*((x[i]-m)**2/(var())))
```

Formula that covers probability mass function for normal distribution looks
[image]
and Maximum Likelihood Function for normal distribution looks
[image].

The function that calculates this estimator is below.

```
def Maximum_Likelihood(param, pmf): # probability mass function, param - parameter for which I want to get estimator
    
    i = symbols('i', positive=True)
    n = symbols('n', positive=True)
    
    Likelihood_function = Product(pmf, (i, 1, n)) 
    
    deriv = diff(Likelihood_function, param) # the problem is here with .diff()
    equation_to_solve = Eq(deriv,0).doit()
    
    return solve(equation_to_solve, param)
```

And when I execute above function for arguments:

```
param = var()
pmf = formula
Maximum_Likelihood(param, pmf)
```

I receive:
*ValueError:  Can't calculate derivative wrt s**2.*

I am aware that `.diff()` [can't calculates derivatives for non-symbols](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#derivative) but I hope that there exists a solution for this problem.

Thank you!

Comment: You could substitute `s` for `sqrt(v)` and then differentiate wrt `v`.

Comment: Thank you Oscar, I made a new symbol `v = symbols('v') # v = variance`, and then used .subs() method for `pmf = formula.subs(s, sqrt(v))` and got the outcome